# XML Parsing: well formed check: undeclared entity

Tags: sql, xml

I am using SSMS 2008 and I am getting the following error.  Do you know what this means?

```
Msg 9448, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
XML parsing: line 1, character 89, well formed check: undeclared entity
```

Here was the code which caused this error:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (j VARCHAR(MAX))
insert into @t
SELECT 
z.MyXml.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') value
FROM  [evolv_cs].[dbo].[progress_note] 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST([progress_note].[note_text] AS XML) [MyXml]) z
```

I also tried this query with same error results:

```
SELECT 
z.MyXml.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') value
INTO #TEMP_PN
FROM  [evolv_cs].[dbo].[progress_note] 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST([progress_note].[note_text] AS XML) [MyXml]) z
```

Here is some sample data before applying this XML statement:

```
<DIV class=gc-message-sms-row><SPAN class=gc-message-sms-from>TLS: </SPAN><SPAN class=gc-message-sms-text>Hi Reggie... I'm on my way to Lynn.. see you soon</SPAN> <SPAN class=gc-message-sms-time>3:09 PM </SPAN></DIV>
<P>List the intervention targeted from the Intermediary Goal: </P> <P>1. To review on call procedure with family.</P> <P>Interventions attempted during the session to target PCP goal(s):&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</P> <P><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; mso-fareast-font-family: 'Times New Roman'; mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-US; mso-bidi-language: AR-SA">Counselor attempted to call mother; however received an automated message stating this number is temporarily out of service.</SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp; </P> <P>Effectiveness of Intervention: </P> <P>Not applicable as family was not available for session.</P> <P>Describe safety plan/PCP crisis plan review (reminder - any modification requires new signatures and safety plans need to be reviewed at a minimum monthly)</P> <P>Not applicable as family was not available for session.</P> <P>Therapeutic Homework Assignment (assignment should relate to intervention and be agreed upon by counselor and family):</P> <P>Not applicable as family was not available for session.</P>
This specialist spoke with Kayla in an attempt to schedule a session for this week.&nbsp; Kayla agreed to meet with this specialist on Friday at 10:30am.&nbsp; This specialist asked Kayla about the upcoming meeting with DCF and Kayla stated that it is about her coming transition, but did not want to discuss it further.&nbsp; Kayla asked if this specialist would meet with her on Monday as well, to take her downtown to go to a meeting at a modeling agency.&nbsp; This specialist stated that this specialist could meet with Kayla prior to that appointment, and then drop Kaya off at the appointment.&nbsp;
<P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal><B><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 9pt">Purpose of Contact:<?xml:namespace prefix = o ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" /><o:p></o:p></SPAN></B></P> <P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 9pt">To coordinate with Structured Day Program Director and notify her that faxed has been sent to refer client to program for summer.<B><o:p></o:p></B></SPAN></P> <P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal><B><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 9pt"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></SPAN></B></P> <P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal><B><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 9pt">Description of Contact:<o:p></o:p></SPAN></B></P> <P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 9pt"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></SPAN></P> <P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 9pt">Counselor spoke with program director to verify she received referral form for client.<SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp; </SPAN>Director confirmed that she received clients referral form but reported that due to the waiting list being so long that client would more than likely not be able to attend program for the summer, but would keep client on waiting list and notify counselor if a slot becomes available.<SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp; </SPAN><SPAN style="mso-spacerun: yes">&nbsp;</SPAN><B><o:p></o:p></B></SPAN></P> <P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal><B><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 9pt"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></SPAN></B></P> <P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal><B><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 9pt">Relationship between contact description and treatment goals:<o:p></o:p></SPAN></B></P> <P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 9pt">An increase in communication between counselor and director will lead to a collaborative treatment approach and improvement in client's referral behaviors. </SPAN><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman','serif'; FONT-SIZE: 12pt"><o:p></o:p></SPAN></P> <P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal><o:p><FONT size=3 face=Calibri>&nbsp;</FONT></o:p></P>
<P style="BACKGROUND: white"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">List the intervention targeted from the Intermediary Goal: The mother will assess what is working well in her home to assist the client with decreasing her referral behaviors.<?xml:namespace prefix = o ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" /><o:p></o:p></SPAN></P> <P style="BACKGROUND: white"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">Interventions attempted during the session to target PCP goal(s):&nbsp;&nbsp;The counselor met with the&nbsp;mother and the client in the home for a face to face session. The counselor noted that the client and the mother were working together to complete household chores. The counselor asked the family to assess if the time frames to complete the chores id effective for the family. The mother and the client reported that the time&nbsp;frames to complete chores are effective. The counselor asked the mother to identify&nbsp;what is effective to assist the client with maintaining her decreased negative behaviors. The mother reported that by educating the client on her expectations and allowing her to make the choice to comply is effective. The counselor and family role played communicating the expectations. The counselor noted that the mother will give the client a directive and allow her a time frame to complete the directive. The client stated that now that her mother leaves her alone once she tells her what to do allow her time to process what her mother wants her to do. The client reported that she does not get upset anymore because she can complete the task&nbsp;within the time frame.<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P> <P style="BACKGROUND: white"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">The counselor and family reviewed personal safety and the court recommendations for the client's protective supervision. The client stated that she is&nbsp;aligned with the&nbsp;following through with the recommendations even while she is on her missions' trip.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <o:p></o:p></SPAN></P> <P style="BACKGROUND: white"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">Effectiveness of Intervention: The intervention appeared to be effective as evidenced by the family's willingness to identify barriers that may prevent them from follow through with identified contingences in the home.<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P> <P style="BACKGROUND: white"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">Describe safety plan/PCP crisis plan review (reminder - any modification requires new signatures and safety plans need to be reviewed at a minimum monthly) The&nbsp;family and counselor reviewed to client's safety plan. No barriers or breakdowns were identified at this time.&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P> <P style="BACKGROUND: white"><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial','sans-serif'; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">Therapeutic Homework Assignment (assignment should relate to intervention and be agreed upon by counselor and family): The mother was asked to review the safety plan with identified supports. The client as asked to follow through with obtaining contact numbers for her new peers from church.<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P> <P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 10pt" class=MsoNormal><o:p><FONT size=3 face=Calibri>&nbsp;</FONT></o:p></P>
```

I finished going through the tutorials Ahmed referenced, but I didn't yet find how to incorporate the HTML DTD into my SQL code.  I see how this might work in an HTML file of course.

So instead I tried replacing all " " occurrences with " " via TSQL, but this gave me a different error: "XML parsing: line 2, character 127, A string literal was expected".  I would still prefer to use the HTML DTD however.  How do I do that with the tsql code above?

What is line 2 referring to?  If it is referring to this sample code then it does not make sense to me.  After replacing all   instances in the sample data above, I looked at line 2 which is the same as line 2 of this sample data.  And character 127 = "v" from "interventions"

Comment: Okay you need to actually show the XML you are parsing; and the ENTITY DTD portions; specifically Line 1 Character 85 - 95  Whatever Entity is there (would be something like &foo;) it is NOT defined in your DTD... More than likely it's an external DTD issue but can't be certain

Comment: u will have to forgive me, Ahmed, but I am really new to XML.  I don't understand what you are requesting.  The sample data that I posted is the [note_text] field from the [evolv_cs].[dbo].[progress_note] table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the entity reference `&nbsp;` in your XML data is not ok because the system can't find the entity named `nbsp`. This typically comes from HTML, not bare XML. Thus you have to use the [HTML DTDs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#dtds) in your DTDs or define that entity manually just like it is done in HTML or simply filter the data textually before doing XML processing on it.

If you use DTD, you could simply write in it:

```
<!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
```

If you do not use them, you simply replace all entity references `&nbsp;` by character references `&#160;`

Comment: Thanks lkuty, I just updated my description.  Can u look at it?  I haven't found how I could incorporate your DTD specification into my tsql code.

Comment: In fact the DOCTYPE declaration which tells where to find the DTD (internal and/or external to the XML document) should be inside the XML data. I don't know if you have the opportunity to do that. Does the sample data represent your data or is there some XML declaration `<?xml ... ?>` at the top of it that we don't see here ? If you can't the easier way is the perform a substring replace on the XML data, replacing any `&nbsp;` by `&#160;`. Note that if you have many different entity references in you XML, this method might not be practical. I would do that as a first attempt.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  No, the sample data is the actual data.  I just want to remove all MS Word metatags.  There is no XML declaration though.  And that is what I did--substring replace on nbsp but then it gave me that second error above.

Comment: OK. Note that `<SPAN class=gc-message-sms-time>` is not XML because the attribute value `gc-message-sms-time` is not enclosed within `"` or `'`. I haven't checked but I guess there is a lot of XML well-formedness errors in the data. Thus you will have to make quite a process of your data before considering it XML or you will have to parse them with an HTML parser but I guess that's not what you want. I suggest you to check for well-formedness errors in an XML aware editor to enumerate the different types of errors and then to try to process them programmatically before parsing it as XML

Comment: Thanks lkuty.  In that case I will have to solve this a different way than XML.  I have learned a lot about XML in the process though.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

XML has only five character entity references: `&lt; &gt; &apos; &quot; &amp;`. The one you are using, `&nbsp;`, is an HTML - but not XML - character entity reference. You can write `&#160;` (decimal) or `&#xA0;` (hex), though.

Comment: "character entity references" does not exist. It is either "character reference" or "entity reference". You can define your own entities using a DTD. The five you mention are the built-in general entities, always available.

Answer (score 2):

:-) No worries.. Okay the issue is (as pointed out by Ikuty below) that   entity is NOT understood by XML... named entities are like nested substitutions (think of them as #defines in C) a DTD (document type definition) will actually map a named entity such as   to a particular character in the target character-set ... That way if you change character-sets you can change the entity definitions in the DTD and your document is still okay.  So..... nbsp is mapped to non-breaking space character #160 in UTF-8 ... There is a nice primer on this topic here:[Making NBSP work with XML](http://changelog.ca/log/2006/06/12/making_nbsp_work_with_xml_rss_and_atom) ... You can find a step by step [XML Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/) at [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com).  Hope this helps as a starting point :-)

Comment: Note that, in the article "Making &nbsp; work in XML, RSS, and Atom", using the word "entity" to identify the thing that is inserted by `&#160;` is wrong. `&#160;` is a character reference and thus a character from the character set is included. It is not an entity reference and thus it does not "point" to an entity.

Comment: @Ahmed: I just updated my description.  Can u look at it?  How could I use lkuty's DTD specification in my tsql code?