# Error with passing XML with special characters through stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have an XML file with special characters such as:

ö ü ü ß

I am getting an error when I try to execute a stored procedure which is meant to populate the database with the xml field values.

The first error I got was:

```
XML parsing: line 55, character 117, well formed check: undeclared entity
```

This is where the special characters were detected. Now after researching into DTD's I added this to the xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE myData [
 <!ENTITY auml    "&#228;" >
 <!ENTITY ouml    "&#246;" >
 <!ENTITY uuml    "&#252;" >
 <!ENTITY szlig   "&#223;" >
 ]>
```

After passing the updated xml file I get another error.
Here is the error:

```
Parsing XML with internal subset DTDs not allowed. Use CONVERT with style option 2 to enable limited internal subset DTD support.
```

Is there a way to handle this exception through C#, modifying the xml file so sql server 2014 can handle the special characters? Or any other way?

Here is the stored procedure I am using:

```
USE [AFFILICAT]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertXML]    Script Date: 25-07-    2015 18:27:34 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- Batch submitted through debugger: XML_Import.sql|0|0|C:\Users\nikhilbanerjee\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\XML_Import.sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertXML]
@xml XML

AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT INTO Programs
  SELECT
  ProgramsStore.value('(description/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS description, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(descriptionLocal/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS descriptionLocal, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(products/text())[1]','INT') AS products, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(vertical/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS vertical, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(regions/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS regions, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('@Id','INT') AS ID, --ATTRIBUTE
  ProgramsStore.value('(Name/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS Name, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(AdRank/text())[1]','FLOAT') AS AdRank, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(startDate/text())[1]','DATE') AS startDate, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(url/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS url, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(image/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS image, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(currency/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(50)') AS currency, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(status/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(10)') AS status, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(terms/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS terms, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(returnTimeLeads/text())[1]','INT') AS returnTimeLeads, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(returnTimeSales/text())[1]','INT') AS returnTimeSales, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(policies/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS policies, --TAG
  ProgramsStore.value('(categories/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS categories --TAG

  FROM
  @xml.nodes('/SearchProgramsResponse/programItems/programItem')AS TEMPTABLE(ProgramsStore)
END
```

And here is my sql connection and sqlcommand execution:

```
        string xml = File.ReadAllText("Programs_modified.xml");

        WebUtility.HtmlEncode(xml);

        try 
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=NIKHIL;Database=AFFILICAT;Trusted_Connection=true"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertXML"))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xml", xml);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {
            string exc = e.Message;
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981636/sql-server-xpath-query-failing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903920/xml-parsing-well-formed-check-undeclared-entity